# CSS text-align right not working. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div style="text-align: left;width: 21cm;">
    <h4 style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;margin: 0">Tax Invoice(Center) <span style="text-align: right;"> For Client(Right)</span></h4>
</div>
```

I want to display text

> For Client(Right)

To the right Side but it displays in the center. How can I display it on the right side?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option

```css
.header-line {
  width:100%;
  background:#eee;
}
.head-33 {
  display:inline-block;
  width:33.3%;
  line-height:48px;
  font-size:1em;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Note: Open div must butt up againsts
     previous close div -->
<div class="header-line"><div 
  class="head-33">Left</div><div 
  class="head-33" style="background:#efe">Center</div><div 
  class="head-33">Right</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="text-align: left;width: 21cm;">
    <h4 style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;margin: 0">Tax Invoice(Center) <span style="float: right;"> For Client(Right)</span></h4>
</div>
```

Use `float: right;` to achieve the desired output

Comment: For Client(Right) Bro, I want to display it to the right side, not on the left side. Tax Invoice(Center) center side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;width: 21cm;margin:auto">
  <span style="text-align: center;width:100%">Tax Invoice(Center)</span><span style="white-space: nowrap">For Client(Right)</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tax Invoice(Center)  For Client(Right)

```html
<div<  style="text-align: left;width: 21cm;">
    <h4 style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;margin: 0">Tax Invoice(Center) <span style="float: right;"> For Client(Right)</span></h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
<span style="text-align: right;"> For Client(Right)</span>
```

You will get the result you want.